# I want to create a parameter value from other parameters

Tags: jenkins, parameters

I want to have 3 parameters that the user enters.  These three will then be used to fill in the final, 4th parameter.  For example:
First name: Bill
Last name: Flow
Job: Engineer

From these the last parameter, Person, will be built: Bill_Flow_Engineer.

I seem to have a ton of options to put in parameters, but I can't seem to find one to do this, at least not without a bunch of code behind it; which I don't mind but would like to keep it simple.

Active Choices x parameter
Dynamic.

N/A

None

This should be a relevant piece of code in the Jenkinfile:

```
 // ----- PERSON -----
if(params.PERSON == null || params.PERSON == "") {
  println("PERSON is empty")
  error("PERSON is empty")
}
else {
  def isMatch = params.PERSON ==~ /[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+/
  if(isMatch) {
    println("PERSON: ${PERSON}")
  }
  else {
    println("PERSON: ${PERSON} is invalid")
    error("PERSON: ${PERSON} is invalid")
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you want the 4th parameter display on Jenkins console, so that user can see it and modify its value?

Comment: I suppose I don't, I want the first 2 fields to be a choice list and the third could be a modifiable default.  So in reality my example isn't great, the first name and last name fields would be pull downs with maybe 5-15 choices and the third field would be some default the user could keep or delete and add their own.  I need the first too fields to be locked in for metrics reporting later.

Comment: It is more helpful to understand the use case when you post the code sample into which you intend to use the fourth parameter. If you just want to create the fourth parameter by concatenating the other three, you can do so in your pipeline in any stage, storing it as a variable before the parameter is called.

Comment: OK, so I list 4 build string parameters, First, Last, Job.  Then I have a fourth string parameter, person, that has a default value of ${First}-${Lastr}-${Job} thus equating to Bill-Flow-Engineer.  Would that be correct?

Comment: Interesting result so far.  if i assign the parameter Person the value of Bill-Flow-Person, it works fine.  But, If i give the parameter Person the value of ${First}-${Lastr}-${Job} I get the following back in the log:

PERSON: Bill-Flow-Engineer is invalid

Comment: Added relevant code to the original question.

Comment: Is there no more interest?